# How to dispatch an input event to textarea element?

Tags: javascript, events

I need to simulate user input into a textarea element and have the input event fire with native JavaScript.

The dispatchEvent below deletes any existing text in the textarea. How do I send the text with this event?

```
element.dispatchEvent(new Event('input', { bubbles: 'true'}));
```

Comment: An input event will not clear the textarea's value. Please add a [mre]/

Comment: Ostone0, you are correct. I had some other code causing the deletion. I still would like to be able to send text though. TX

Comment: That's not possible, just set the `value`